# ¿Como puedo modificar internamente una columna de un archivo .csv en python?

Tags: python, csv

Tengo el siguiente archivo .csv:

```
"Date","Wind Speed","Rain","Solar Radiation", "Temp"
11/25/19 18:20:00,4.7,0.0,"1,166",13.79
11/25/19 18:30:00,4.7,0.0,"1,089",13.81
11/25/19 18:40:00,4.9,0.0,"1,059",13.76
11/25/19 18:50:00,5.5,0.0,"1,121",12.44
11/25/19 19:00:00,4.5,0.0,"1,042",13.55
11/25/19 19:10:00,4.3,0.0,878,14.15
```

Los valores "1,166", "1,089", "1,059", etc, en realidad son valores miles, que el programa que crea el .csv los entrega de esa forma (no modificable) provocando un conflicto al posteriormente agregarlos a una base de datos.

¿Como puedo modificar esa columna para que transforme los valores que están entre comillas a valores miles (y junto con eso desaparezcan las comillas)?

Comment: No me queda claro si lo que buscas es una solución desde `mysql` o desde `python`

Comment: Perdón, no lo especifiqué. Desde python. @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En python, la forma más compacta es hacer uso de [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) para leer el archivo y  [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) para escribirlo nuevamente:

```
import csv

with open('archivo.csv') as csv_file:
  with open('archivo_limpio.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
      row[3] = row[3].replace(",","")
      csv.writer(out_file).writerow(row)
```

La idea es simple, leemos `archivo.csv` fila por fila y eliminamos la `,` de la cuarta columna, para finalmente volverlo a salvar en `archivo_limpio.csv`. Si quieres pasarle por parámetro los nombres de archivo, puedes modificar ligeramente el código, reemplazando los nombres de los archivos por el parámetro de linea de comando `sys.argv[1]` y `sys.argv[2]` para indicar el archivo de entrada y salida, finalmente la ejecución sería algo así:

```
python script.py archivo.csv archivo_limpio.csv
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. El código crea el archivo_limpio.csv tal cual como lo esperaba.

¡Gracias Patricio!